# How do I package my appjs app?

Tags: appjs, software-packaging

I'm trying to release a package for my appjs app but there doesn't seem to be any easy way for end users to "just run" the application without a terminal.

Is there anyway to do this that is fool proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've found an easy way to do this, not necessarily the easiest way but it works.

## OSx

I use [this bash script](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps) to convert my folder to a .app folder (which is all OSx needs apparently)

## Windows

and on Windows I use [IsTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) to create my in/un-staller and shortcuts.

## Linux

I've not found an easy peasy way to do this on Linux yet but we don't have a customer base on Linux so it doesn't matter. I have however found [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html) but it seems awefully convoluted. Shan't bother for now.

Comment: I like the solution for OSx I will have to take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the distributable for your platform from: http://appjs.org/#download. Then it includes a launch script -- app.exe for windows and app.sh for linux / mac os which launches everything without a console.

There is also an addition to appjs that installs appjs as a platform feature (rather than having the whole runtime in each application you distribute). Using this you can compile your application into a single file which you can then distribute to end users. This functionality is being actively developed and improved. http://appjs.delightfulsoftware.com/. see also screenshot tour for windows: http://appjs.delightfulsoftware.com/win.htm and for ubuntu linux: http://appjs.delightfulsoftware.com/ubuntu.htm.

/Simon

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I've found two other ways to do this an easier way.